# GeoServer behind Nginx: web admin crashes

Tags: geoserver, proxy, nginx

I have set up GeoServer to run behind an Nginx proxy as follows:

```
listen 443 ssl http2 ;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2 ;

location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/;
}
```

It is serving up map layers perfectly this way. However, when I try to log into the admin panel, I get the following error:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /geoserver/web/;jsessionid=swynjc84o5oz1k0uu6xkhf9c7. Reason:

    Server Error
Caused by:

org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String ";"
    at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall.rejectedBlacklistedUrls(StrictHttpFirewall.java:265)
    at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall.getFirewalledRequest(StrictHttpFirewall.java:245)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:193)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I'm not very adept at Java server configurations, and only tangentially with Nginx administration. My guess is that there is some issue here in the way Nginx is proxying requests.

I have searched for answers on this issue, but only come up with solutions for Apache servers.

**Update:** after some more testing, I found out that I can get the admin web portal working using the following:

```
location /geoserver/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/;
}
```

I think this narrows the issue down to Nginx configuration. Here's what I'm trying to achieve: use a URL like `https://geoserver.myserver.com/[...]` instead of using `https://geoserver.myserver.com/geoserver/[...]`.

Comment: Probably needs fixing in server.xml file on Tomcat

Comment: I had the same problem using Apache2 and was also able to solve it by appending `/geoserver` to the proxypass address. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to get it working with the following Nginx settings:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/;
    proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

location /geoserver/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/;
    proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

To get layer previews to work, I also added my domain name under `Settings > Global > Proxy Base URL` in the GeoServer admin site:

```
https://mydomain.com
```

and make sure to check `Use headers for Proxy URL`.

After that I reloaded the configuration

```
Server Status > Reload
```

reloaded Nginx

```
sudo service nginx reload
```

and restarted GeoServer

```
./bin/shutdown.sh
./bin/startup.sh
```

**What this achieves:**

- Puts the site behind SSL.
- WMS URLS do not include the redundant geoserver directory.
- The admin portal now works and lets users log in.

**What I haven't been able to get working yet:**

- The URLs in the admin portal still contain the `geoserver` folder, as in `https://geoserver.myserver.com/geoserver/web`, for many pages. This doesn't seem to affect functionality, though, and since it's only in the admin portal, I'll be the only one who sees it.

Comment: This location blocks configuration works for me for http only. When I add `listen 443 ssl`  and SSL certificates instead of just `listen 80`, it loads the geoserver home page with https, but admin login redirects to `http://<my-host>/geoserver/j_spring_security_check` showing `The information you’re about to submit is not secure`. Is there something that I am missing in the configuration?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to the login form redirect problem?

Comment: @Shayne I'm not sure that I have, it has been some time since I worked with geoserver due to a change in employment.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known issue](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-8913) and is due to an (unplanned) increase in security when Spring was upgraded.

One suggested work around is to add

```
<session-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

to the `web.xml` file.

Comment: While I have seen numerous articles and posts referencing this issue, I think it may have been resolved, at least on Linux, as I was able to get it working without making this change, and prior I had it working (but in that case WMS URLs wouldn't work). I posted my solution to get it working, I hope I didn't miss anything. Thanks for your suggestion, though. :)