# Use Nginx with Tomcat to put GeoServer under HTTPS

Tags: geoserver, tomcat, nginx

I'm trying to use HTTPS with GeoServer. I've used [this steps](https://gist.github.com/MaxDragonheart/00a90b48100f8ef4f8c452a79bf9000c) to install Tomcat, Nginx and GeoServer on Ubuntu 20.04. At the end I've used the [wizard](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntufocal-nginx) from certbot for enable HTTPS.

I can access without problems to my webserver and to GeoServer using `https://gis.domain.it`.

The problems comes when I try to create something. For example if I try to create a *Workspace* or a *Store* I see this error:

> HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request Type Status Report
>
> Message Origin does not correspond to request
>
> Description The server cannot or will not process the request due to
> something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed
> request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request
> routing).
>
> Apache Tomcat/9.0.37

I think that the problem is into the configuration of Nginx but I'm not sure of this. I found [this solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/306890/72195) for a problem like mine but it doesn't seem to work.

Any solutions?

I must use the OGC service under HTTPS but I've not strong skills on this field and I'm learning how to do.

**FOCUS ON NGINX INSTALLATION**
I've used the steps belove to install and configure Nginx

> ### 3. Configure Nginx Proxy for Tomcat
>
> #### 3.1 Install Nginx
>
> ```
> apt install nginx -y
> ```
>
> #### 3.2 Create a new virtual host configuration file for Tomcat
>
> ```
> nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/tomcat.conf
>  Add the following lines:
>
> server {
>   listen 80;
>
>   server_name    example.com www.example.com;
>   access_log /var/log/nginx/tomcat-access.log;
>   error_log /var/log/nginx/tomcat-error.log;
>
>   location / {
>         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
>         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
>         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
>         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Then enable virtual host file and restart Nginx
>
> ```
> ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/tomcat.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
> systemctl restart nginx
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are experiencing a Cross-Site Request Forgery problem, GeoServer thinks that some one is spoofing your requests. This is solved by adding the proxy to a "white" or allowed list of machines that can make requests.

This is described on in the [GeoServer manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/webadmin/csrf.html)