# Correct way to get SSL working with Tomcat GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/1051660/nginx-proxy-to-tomcat-with-ssl) but the configurations look quite long so I'm not sure if they're suitable for my simpler case. What guide explains setting up SSL properly? [This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/370337/use-nginx-with-tomcat-to-put-geoserver-under-https) post doesn't show the SSL stuff. When I log in I get http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/j_spring_security_check, unable to connect.

Comment: looks like a CSRF issue as in the linked question's answer

Comment: I already whitelisted the domain. It's something else.

Comment: did you set the proxy url correctly?

Comment: It was set correctly but now it won't let me log in for some reason. It tries to open http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/j_spring_security_check and 'unable to connect'.

Comment: I just made a second instance on AWS as a fresh start. Should I put my https domain as the proxy URL before installing Nginx and Certbot?

Comment: If your proxy is set correctly you would not end up with localhost 8080. Install nginx get proxying working then add SSL , rembering to change the proxy url

Comment: What article explains how to do that correctly? I see a bunch for Tomcat 10 but I'm on 9 because I think that's what the docs recommend. Should I just use 10?

Comment: I upgraded to Debian Testing which has Tomcat 10 and Java 17 but now Geoserver won't even open on http://192.168.0.12:8080/geoserver. 404 not found.

Comment: So the steps are install Nginx, point it to Tomcat, run Certbot, add proxy base url, whitelist domain? I did exactly those steps, and now I'm right back where I started where OpenLayers aren't opening right. What could I possibly be missing?

Comment: what have you set your proxy_url to? did the nginx forwarding work before you ran certbot? Did you read [the page](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/java.html) on supported Java versions?

Comment: Proxy Base URL is https://daniellinux.com/geoserver. If 'works' means I can log in to the main GUI without a problem and it says https in the url then yes. Yes, I'm running Java 11.

Comment: if you can log in what is the issue?

Comment: Well now the last six previews don't display anything though the box GUI still opens. But where is this geoserver.log file mentioned in the other thread?

Comment: The stuff in the ne directory are what aren't getting displayed.

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: It's in the other thread.