# http 400 - Bad Request when I try to change master password on GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, tomcat, ssl, nginx

I've installed GeoServer on Tomcat9 & nginx as proxy server. By the help of [this beautiful answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306824/geoserver-behind-nginx-web-admin-crashes/306890#306890), it started working nice with Let's Encrypt SSL certificate.

However, when I go to security/passwords, then click on 'Change password', I am receiving the error message below:

```
HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request

Type Status Report

Message Origin does not correspond to request

Description The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).
Apache Tomcat/9.0.58 (Ubuntu)
```

And the url is like:

https://mydomain.tld/geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.security.web.passwd.PasswordPage?4-1.ILinkListener-form-changePassword&filter=false

Then I check it without my domain (nginx), the url is:

http://my.ip.address:8080/geoserver/web/wicket/page?21

What could be the reason for this error?

Comment: Sounds like a CSRF issue, did you white list your address

Comment: See https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/webadmin/csrf.html